# Efficiently extracting data from a generator

Tags: python, dictionary, generator

I am just learning python and I am wondering if there is a better way to extract the most current temperature from the res variable.

```
from noaa_sdk import noaa
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
n = noaa.NOAA()
res = n.get_observations('25311', 'US', start=date, end=None, num_of_stations=1)
temp= (next(res))
value =(temp.get('temperature'))
temperature = (value['value'])
temperature = temperature*9/5+32
print(temperature, ' F')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is reasonably efficient, but it could be trimmed down to:

#### Code:

```
from noaa_sdk import noaa
import datetime as dt

date = dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
res = noaa.NOAA().get_observations('25311', 'US', start=date)
print('{:.1f} F'.format( next(res)['temperature']['value'] * 9 / 5 + 32))
```

#### Results:

```
44.1 F
```

Answer (score 0):

If you meant computational efficiency, there is not much room to improve it.

If you meant shorter lines of code, `temp= (next(res))` part, which has anything to do with extracting data in your code, seems already very short.

Answer (score 0):

The example docs for the `noaa_sdk` package make heavy use of loops. I would suggest, if you're just learning Python, that you try to use a loop-oriented style.

```
from datetime import datetime

from noaa_sdk import noaa

def to_freedom_degrees(temp_c):
    return 32.0 + 9.0 / 5.0 * temp_c

date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
observations = noaa.NOAA().get_observations('25311', 'US', start=date, end=None, num_of_stations=1)

for observation in observations:
    temp_c = observation['temperature']
    temp_f = to_freedom_degrees(temp_c)
    print(temperature, ' F')
    # I only want one temperature
    break
else:
    print('No temperature found!')
```